# CSS float list of elements on the right

Tags: css, angular

I am building a chat application as follows. I would like to have the messages float on the right in new lines.

[image]

My typescript looks like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor = "let message of messages">
    <div class="message-content pull-right">
        <div style="display: block;">
            {{message}}
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
.message-content {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #b2e281;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0.2em 0.5em;
    max-width: calc(60%);
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.pull-right {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap it in another div, make that div the full width of the chat box, and use flex to align it to the right side:

```
<ng-container *ngFor = "let message of messages">
    <div class="pull-right">
        <div class="message-content">
            <div style="display: block;">
                {{message}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</ng-container>
```

```
.message-content {
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #b2e281;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0.2em 0.5em;
    max-width: calc(60%);
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
.pull-right {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justifyContent: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This should work like you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

My proposal would be to not use inline styles and keep it simple with block/inline block. Hope this works well for you:

```
<ng-container *ngFor = "let message of messages">
  <div class="message-content">
        <div class="message-content__item">{{message}}</div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

And CCS:

```
.message-content {
  display: block;
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}
.message-content__item {
  background-color: #b2e281;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0.2em 0.5em;
  width: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

https://codepen.io/gretakavaliauskaite/pen/eYdbRBQ